# Check if jobject is an array using Java JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Suppose I got a jobject of unknown (arbitrary) type in JNI code. How can I check if it's an array? Extra points for finding type of array elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, JNI doesn't seem to provide shortcut function to check for an array, so one has to emulate call to standard Java method `Class.isArray` (obj is jobject to test):

```
jmethodID Class_isArray_m = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, Class_class, "isArray", "()Z");
jclass obj_class = (*env)->GetObjectClass(obj);
jboolean is_array = (*env)->CallBooleanMethod(obj_class, Class_isArray_mid);
```

Element type can be found in similar way using `Class.getComponentType()`. However, depending on what native code wants to do, it may be easier to just get encoded type name using `Class.getName()` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()) and parse it - an array type starts with '[', if there's single letter after it, it's array of primitive types, otherwise it's object array (in particular, it may be multidimensional array).